# Python tika on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, apache-tika

I'm using [tika](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python) to parse pdf files that I have to work on. The application automatically launches TikaServerCli, but on Heroku I get "RuntimeError: Unable to start Tika server."

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715589/tika-server-on-heroku) and could make it work locally with the following Procfile (I downloaded tika-server-1.26.jar to my computer).

```
web: gunicorn main:app
tika: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar tika-server-1.26.jar --host=0.0.0.0 --port=$PORT
```

The above works perfectly on my machine with "heroku local", but on Heroku it now doesn't recognize the bash command java:

```
2021-05-06T17:59:13.415018+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar tika-server-1.26.jar --host=0.0.0.0 --port=51171`

2021-05-06T17:59:16.376706+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: java: command not found
```

The project on Heroku is configured to use Python. Can I tell Heroku to recognize Java commands as well? Alternatively, is there a way to change the "tika:" command in the Procfile to use Python, or is there another way to use tika on Heroku?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995929/my-heroku-python-app-needs-java-to-be-installed It's helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @PCP. I tried adding buildpacks for jvm and JS as well, but still had no luck. In the end I decided to change my whole project and not use Tika because of this (the code had been ready to deploy for over 1 week). I was only using it to extract text from a PDF file. I changed to PDFminer.six and it worked just fine on Heroku. 
Thanks for the reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add heroku/jvm buildpack. Try:

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm
```